# How to install "NimbusSanL-Regu" font in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, fonts

I need to install the "NimbusSanL-Regu" font in Ubuntu 18.04 using cmd.
I will try with sudo apt-get install fonts-Nimbus or other command but it is not working for me.

Comment: To be discoverable by google, my error message is `Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: File not found: "NimbusRomNo9L-Reg.otf".`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's provided by the `gsfonts` package in the Ubuntu archive.

```
sudo apt install gsfonts
```

On my machine I see these Nimbus fonts:

```
$ fc-match -a | grep -i nimbus
n019003l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular"
n019043l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular Condensed"
n019004l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Bold"
n019044l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Bold Condensed"
n019023l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular Italic"
n019063l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular Condensed Italic"
n019024l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Bold Italic"
n019064l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Bold Condensed Italic"
n021003l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Regular"
n022003l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Regular"
n021004l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Medium"
n022004l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Bold"
n021023l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Regular Italic"
n021024l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Medium Italic"
n022023l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Regular Oblique"
n022024l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Bold Oblique"
```

Answer (score 6):

That font is included in the `gsfonts` package. You can install it like this:

```
sudo apt install gsfonts
```

If you don't want to install that package, you can download the font from [ttfonts.net](https://ttfonts.net/font/28389_NimbusSanL.htm). Execute this in a terminal:

```
wget --no-check-certificate "http://ttfonts.net/sfonts/2/27260_NimbusSanL.ttf"
gnome-font-viewer 27260_NimbusSanL.ttf
```

Then click 'Install'.